# Why does my Visual Studio 2010 Silverlight solution completely break on "Clean"?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference, namespaces, silverlight-5.0, solution

Previous to cleaning, everything built correctly, and I was able to make significant changes/rebuild throughout the day.  I decided to "Clean Solution" and that promptly broke everything.  Any reference to namespaces could not be found, as seen in the error below:

`The type or namespace name '(insert_name)' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

In this solution, it accounted for 631 errors.  No rebuilding/building combination seemed to fix it.  I had difficulty finding much about this online, so thought I'd post here to see if anyone had some idea.

It may also be worth noting that this solution was simply copied to my machine from a coworker's, so it may have something to do with that?  Although, it built perfectly fine previous to cleaning.  Thoughts?

Comment: There may have been some dependencies in the files that you copied from your coworker's machine that got removed by cleaning the solution.

Comment: Right, it just seems strange to me that I was able to make changes throughout the day without anything breaking.  I have the entire project folder, containing all Lib references, etc.  Perhaps a discrepancy in file paths or something similar?

Comment: Could be; obviously I can only speculate. My approach for debugging this kind of problem is to do a full build again, and look at the raw output log. Find the very first error that comes up, and fix it. Then rebuild and repeat. Often you'll see one or two errors that are causing all the rest.

Comment: Sometimes I've also seen problems like this caused by incorrectly defined build dependencies between your assemblies (the ones you're trying to build); though this should just be fixed, it can sometimes be worked around by running the build multiple times. However, you say "No rebuilding/building combination seemed to fix it," so it sounds like you already tried this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following possibilities:

- you have some references to libraries that use an absolute path that is valid on one machine and not another. For instance, you use Silverlight Toolkit and it's not installed on both machines, or one of the computers is 32 bits and the other 64 bits, and you get Program Files (x86) on the x64 only.
- you have some references to libraries that use a relative path that is valid on one machine and not another. For instance you have X:\Work\Project\Project.sln which references X:\Work\Tools\Library.dll using ..\..\Tools\Library.dll, and the other machine has it in X:\Work\Tools\SomeLib\Library.dll.

In both cases, you should see a 'root' error indicating a library's DLL wasn't found. Sometimes, looking at the Output window instead of the Errors window makes it easier to spot.

Comment: Just to followup on this... oddly enough I copied over the same project folder again, built and ran fine.  I then cleaned without error, built and ran still without error.  As I start reapplying the changes I made the other day I will periodically clean to see at which point the solution breaks

Comment: Maybe it won't break this time :)

Comment: Going back to this... never did find the exact cause for the catastrophic breaking of the solution, but was not able to recreate with a fresh copy.